# NGINX fails at COPY --from=node /app/dist/comp-lib /usr/share/nginx/html,

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/1e9a0e53a11b406c13d4fc790336f37285927a1b87d1bac4d0e889c6d3cfed9b/merged/app/dist/comp-lib: no such file or directory

I tried running `docker system prune`, and restarted Docker a bunch of times.  I also gave a shot at `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` in the docker VM, somehow that doesn't remove the directory.

Node version: v10.15.1

Docker version: 18.09.2, build 6247962

Dockerfile:

```
# stage-1

FROM node as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# stage -2

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/comp-lib /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I expect the build to be successful but the above mentioned is the error I'm experiencing.

Comment: When you run `docker build`, after it prints out each `RUN` line, it will print a hex ID; that's a valid Docker image ID.  You should be able to `docker run --rm -it 0123456789ab sh` using the image ID at the end of your builder stage.  Is what's in the `/app/dist` directory what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

In your stage 2

```
COPY --from=node /app/dist/comp-lib /usr/share/nginx/html
```

should be

```
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/comp-lib /usr/share/nginx/html
```

since stage 1 is called `builder` and not `node`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the dockerfile that I use for my Angular apps:

```
FROM johnpapa/angular-cli as angular-built
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Preston Lamb"
COPY --from=angular-built /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

I've never had any issues with this configuration. [There's more information as well in this article](https://www.prestonlamb.com/blog/dockerizing-angular).